# Substring - Fastest way

Tags: sql, oracle11g, informatica-powercenter

I would like to substring different values from a string.
The string is usually about 700 characters long and contains ~40 Attributes, which are looking like "City=Paris".

edit: I want only the value behind the equal sign, Paris.

Now my solution would look like this:

```
IIF(instr(in_Logfile_Input,'Country=',1,1)>0, substr(in_Logfile_Input, 
instr(in_Logfile_Input,'Country=',1,1)+8,instr(in_Logfile_Input,';',
instr(in_Logfile_Input,'Country=',1,1),1)-instr(in_Logfile_Input,'Country=',1,1)-9),
'n/a')
```

The amount of data to be processed is about 3-4 million rows a day. 
My solution works, but im looking for a more structured and faster solution.

Regards
Thomas

Comment: My gut feeling says that `REGEXP_REPLACE` could be a better choice.  I do not know it for a fact.

Comment: I tried using solving this with reg_expr, but unfortunately its about 50-70% slower than my given solution :(

Comment: OK. Then you know better. My reasoning was that as a brand new feature `REGEXP_REPLACE` would be better optimized.

Comment: I assume that kind of data ultimately comes from a text file.  You may want to directly read from the file with an external table or sqlldr.

Comment: I would preprocess the text file with a shell file, launched with a Command task. You could produce a CSV or a fixed width file. I think this would be much faster.

Comment: you could create a function based index on your instr function or write the results of your function to another column in the table